# Override error message in spring validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator

Say I make rest service with Spring.

Say I need custom validator wich is applied to whole type/class i.e. @Target({ElementType.TYPE}). Validator has pretty clumsy logic which cannot be reduced to subvalidators or field-validators.

So sometimes it is rather difficult to understand what exactly is wrong and I need to add different error messages.

I can't get how to do that. Is it possible?

For example like:

```
public class ReportConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidReport, Report> {

    @Autowired
    DesignRepository designRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidReport constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Report report, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ...
        // here goes "foo error message"
        return false;
        ...
        // here goes "bar error message"
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a spring `Validator` instead of a `javax.validation` one or checkout the documentation of [`ConstraintValidatorContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html#buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @M.Deinum That's exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as M.Denium proposed

```
public class ReportConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidReport, Report> {

@Autowired
DesignRepository designRepository;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidReport constraintAnnotation) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Report report, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    ...
    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("foo error message").addConstraintViolation();
    return false;
    ...
    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("foo error message").addConstraintViolation();
    return false;
}
}
```